# Django get all ManyToMany relationships of an object

Tags: python, django, django-models

All my models have several ManyToMany relationships with other models and themselves, and they all have a "through" table

Let's say I have model `A` , that has a `ManyToManyField` with model `B` and `C`, let's also consider the field name is the same as the related model

And I have model `D` that has a ManyToManyField with model `A`.

Now, I want to get all objects related to an `A` object of classes `B`, `C` and `D`

This is what I had tried :

```
a1 = A.objects.get(pk = 1)
#Get all B objects related to A
a1.b.all()
#Get all C objects related to A
a1.c.all()
#Get all D objects related to A but from D class because that's where the field is
#Raises error 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'
D.a.all(pk=1)
```

Actual models can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/UQxwpbdN) (My problem is with Pessoa and CCir).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `a.d_set.all()` in order to get reverse relation, or with the code you've provided:

```
obj = Pessoa.objects.get(pk=1) # get the object
obj.ccir_set.all()
```

Also you might consider providing `related_name` for your m2m models